# Which grammars are written with TeX?

Tags: reference-request, latex

I have an enduring interest in TeX, and was pleasantly surprised that Schiffman's *Reference Grammar of Spoken Tamil* (1999) namechecks Knuth in the foreword. I would like to ask for other examples of grammars written with TeX or its derivatives, in particular ones that have caught your eye for their masterful typesetting. The rise of Language Science Press in this regard is great, but I would be particularly interested in older works. Access to source code not required.

Comment: [This one](https://www.academia.edu/7017345/Old_English_and_Old_Norse_Introduction_to_West_and_North_Germanic) was definitely set in some form of TeX, but I’m not sure if you’d call it ‘a grammar’, since it’s not published (it was originally written by a former instructor of mine as handout material for a class in Germanic).

Comment: Are you including LaTeX? If so, there are many as it's been quite popular with linguists.

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut I am ("or its derivatives"). I realise that TeX is popular with linguists, but many published book-length grammars are typeset in-house and thus tend to use more professional workflows.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet that one is awesome! Thanks.

Comment: So you only want published grammars? The ones I had in mind were written in LaTeX, not sure what happened when/if they were published. For example, [Here's](https://openresearch-repository.anu.edu.au/handle/1885/145308) a grammar  of Awa Pit (Colombia) written in LaTeX.

Comment: [Here's another one](https://openresearch-repository.anu.edu.au/handle/1885/12678), a grammar of Ibaloy (Austronesian, Philippines).